# How can I add an image to the specific layer of psd file using ag-psd module in react project?

Tags: reactjs, psd

I am gonna add an image to the specific layer of psd file using ag-psd module in react project.
In other words, I want to add an image as the cover of book.
See this image, please.

[image: image of work in progress]

```
const replacelayerName = 'replace';
const replacelayer = psd.children.find((child) => child.name === replacelayerName);

if (replacelayer && replacelayer.canvas) {
    const myImage = await loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(imageFile));
    replacelayer.canvas.width = myImage.width;
    replacelayer.canvas.height = myImage.height; 
    replacelayer.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
        
const newPsd = writePsd(psd);

...

*setMockupPreview(newPsd.canvas.toDataURL());* Here error occurs.
```

Comment: if that code is part of the question there's an edit button so you can include it

Comment: I want your kindly help. Not sure?

Comment: What's the error you're experiencing?